# Displaying existing content in Rails 5.2 with ActionText

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actiontext

I have upgraded my app to rails 5.2 and inclined to use ActionText since old trix-editor/gem is no longer working.
Now new posts display their "descriptions" but how can I display my old posts' DESCRIPTIONS with the new installed ActionText?

post.rb `has_rich_text :description`

posts_controller.rb
`...params.require(:post).permit(:description)`

_form.html.erb
`<%= f.rich_text_area :description %>`

show.html.erb
`<%= @post.description %>`

Descriptions are only fetching from new records in ActionText but not displaying from existing "description" columns for old posts

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and I couldn't find a clean solution in the rails repo or anywhere. As a workaround, in your case, I would try:

> **show.html.erb:** .
>   `<%= @post.try(:description).body || @post[:description] %>`

That wont solve the issue, but it would help you to populate old post values.

Answer (score 0):

This answer worked for me. It also has the added bonus of cleaning up your database of the tables used for the normal (non-rich) text content.

"Assuming there's a 'content' in your model and that's what you want to migrate, first, add to your model: "

```
has_rich_text :content
```

"then create a migration"

```sh
rails g migration MigratePostContentToActionText
```

```
class MigratePostContentToActionText < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
  def change
    rename_column :posts, :content, :content_old
    Post.all.each do |post|
      post.update_attribute(:content, simple_format(post.content_old))
    end
    remove_column :posts, :content_old
  end
end
```

You can find the original solution I used here
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/35002#issuecomment-562311492