# Rails 6 ActionText get first image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, actiontext

I have Post model:

```rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_rich_text :content
end
```

On `Post#index` I want to display a post with title, an image and description. For image and description, how I could get those from ActionText?

I think get first image ~ get first active storage blob (belongs to the Post) which content_type is image.

```
irb(main):017:0> Post.last.content
  Post Load (22.6ms)  SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` ORDER BY `posts`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  ActionText::RichText Load (3.2ms)  SELECT `action_text_rich_texts`.* FROM `action_text_rich_texts` WHERE `action_text_rich_texts`.`record_id` = 12 AND `action_text_rich_texts`.`record_type` = 'Post' AND `action_text_rich_texts`.`name` = 'content' LIMIT 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):17
  Rendered /Users/stronglong/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.0.rc2/app/views/action_text/attachables/_remote_image.html.erb (Duration: 4.0ms | Allocations: 54)
  Rendered /Users/stronglong/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.0.rc2/app/views/action_text/attachables/_remote_image.html.erb (Duration: 0.2ms | Allocations: 52)
  Rendered /Users/stronglong/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.0.rc2/app/views/action_text/attachables/_remote_image.html.erb (Duration: 0.2ms | Allocations: 52)
  Rendered /Users/stronglong/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.0.rc2/app/views/action_text/attachables/_remote_image.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 52)
  Rendered /Users/stronglong/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.0.rc2/app/views/action_text/attachables/_remote_image.html.erb (Duration: 0.6ms | Allocations: 52)
  Rendered /Users/stronglong/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.0.rc2/app/views/action_text/attachables/_remote_image.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 52)
  Rendered /Users/stronglong/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.0.rc2/app/views/action_text/attachables/_remote_image.html.erb (Duration: 0.8ms | Allocations: 52)
  Rendered /Users/stronglong/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.0.rc2/app/views/action_text/attachables/_remote_image.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 52)
  Rendered /Users/stronglong/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.0.rc2/app/views/action_text/attachables/_remote_image.html.erb (Duration: 0.2ms | Allocations: 52)
  Rendered /Users/stronglong/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.0.rc2/app/views/action_text/attachables/_remote_image.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 52)
  Rendered /Users/stronglong/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.0.rc2/app/views/action_text/attachables/_remote_image.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 52)
  Rendered /Users/stronglong/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.0.rc2/app/views/action_text/attachables/_remote_image.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 52)
  Rendered /Users/stronglong/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.0.rc2/app/views/action_text/attachables/_remote_image.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 52)
  Rendered /Users/stronglong/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.0.rc2/app/views/action_text/attachables/_remote_image.html.erb (Duration: 0.3ms | Allocations: 52)
  Rendered /Users/stronglong/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.0.rc2/app/views/action_text/attachables/_remote_image.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 52)
  Rendered /Users/stronglong/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.0.rc2/app/views/action_text/attachables/_remote_image.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 52)
  Rendered /Users/stronglong/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.0.rc2/app/views/action_text/attachables/_remote_image.html.erb (Duration: 0.2ms | Allocations: 52)
  Rendered /Users/stronglong/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.0.rc2/app/views/action_text/attachables/_remote_image.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 52)
  Rendered /Users/stronglong/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.0.rc2/app/views/action_text/content/_layout.html.erb (Duration: 445.6ms | Allocations: 54464)
NoMethodError (undefined method `first' for #<ActionText::RichText:0x00007fb0a9e33620>)
irb(main):018:0> Post.last.content.body
  Post Load (1.6ms)  SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` ORDER BY `posts`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  ActionText::RichText Load (3.4ms)  SELECT `action_text_rich_texts`.* FROM `action_text_rich_texts` WHERE `action_text_rich_texts`.`record_id` = 12 AND `action_text_rich_texts`.`record_type` = 'Post' AND `action_text_rich_texts`.`name` = 'content' LIMIT 1
  Rendered /Users/stronglong/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.0.rc2/app/views/action_text/attachables/_remote_image.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 54)
  Rendered /Users/stronglong/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.0.rc2/app/views/action_text/attachables/_remote_image.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 52)
  Rendered /Users/stronglong/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.0.rc2/app/views/action_text/attachables/_remote_image.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 52)
  Rendered /Users/stronglong/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.0.rc2/app/views/action_text/attachables/_remote_image.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 52)
  Rendered /Users/stronglong/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.0.rc2/app/views/action_text/attachables/_remote_image.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 52)
  Rendered /Users/stronglong/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.0.rc2/app/views/action_text/attachables/_remote_image.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 52)
  Rendered /Users/stronglong/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.0.rc2/app/views/action_text/attachables/_remote_image.html.erb (Duration: 0.3ms | Allocations: 52)
  Rendered /Users/stronglong/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.0.rc2/app/views/action_text/attachables/_remote_image.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 52)
  Rendered /Users/stronglong/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.0.rc2/app/views/action_text/attachables/_remote_image.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 52)
  Rendered /Users/stronglong/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.0.rc2/app/views/action_text/attachables/_remote_image.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 52)
  Rendered /Users/stronglong/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.0.rc2/app/views/action_text/attachables/_remote_image.html.erb (Duration: 0.2ms | Allocations: 52)
  Rendered /Users/stronglong/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.0.rc2/app/views/action_text/attachables/_remote_image.html.erb (Duration: 0.2ms | Allocations: 52)
  Rendered /Users/stronglong/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.0.rc2/app/views/action_text/attachables/_remote_image.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 52)
  Rendered /Users/stronglong/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.0.rc2/app/views/action_text/attachables/_remote_image.html.erb (Duration: 0.2ms | Allocations: 52)
  Rendered /Users/stronglong/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.0.rc2/app/views/action_text/attachables/_remote_image.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 52)
  Rendered /Users/stronglong/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.0.rc2/app/views/action_text/attachables/_remote_image.html.erb (Duration: 0.7ms | Allocations: 52)
  Rendered /Users/stronglong/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.0.rc2/app/views/action_text/attachables/_remote_image.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 52)
  Rendered /Users/stronglong/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.0.rc2/app/views/action_text/attachables/_remote_image.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 52)
  Rendered /Users/stronglong/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.0.rc2/app/views/action_text/content/_layout.html.erb (Duration: 115.7ms | Allocations: 53442)
=> #<ActionText::Content "<div class=\"trix-conte...">
```

Ref: for description I see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56816455/displaying-existing-content-in-rails-5-2-with-actiontext)

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Roland for the answer, it should be accepted.

To avoid N+1 queries add with_rich_text_[ATTRIBUTE]_and_embeds.
https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_text_overview.html#avoid-n-1-queries

Content in my model is in the *text* attribute.

posts_controller.rb

```
@post = Post.with_rich_text_text_and_embeds.find(params[:id])
```

show.html.erb

```
<% if !post.text.embeds.empty? %>
    <%= image_tag post.text.embeds.find{|embeds| embeds.image?}.variant(resize_to_limit: [200, 200]) %>
<% end %>
```

Will appreciate any more effective solution.

Answer (score 3):

The `ActionText` model provides the association `embeds`, so you can just call `find` on that with the handy method `image?`

```
Post.last
    .with_rich_text_text_and_embeds # to avoid N+1 queries
    .content
    .embeds
    .find{|embeds| embeds.image?} # to make sure embed is an image
```

Comment: If someone knows how we can achieve this with some joins for more efficient queries, I would appreciate such an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `content.to_plain_text` to get the text and `content.embeds` to get all attachments (play with the association to get the first image since it can embed other things)

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actiontext/app/models/action_text/rich_text.rb

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```rb
Post.last.rich_text_content.embeds.joins(:blob)
    .find_by("active_storage_blobs.content_type ~* '^image'")
```

It performs 3 queries though, and assumes a postgresql database.